# Problem syncing to mainnet

Tags: go-ethereum, mainnet

I've successfully synced to `mainnet` in light mode, but I'm trying to do so with `--syncmode snap`.

I can see that there are peers connected using the `net.peerCount` on the IPC. However, when I use `eth.syncing`, it shows `false`. I'm not sure what's happening. It did not do so when running on light mode.